# How to use receivedDateTime in Graph API Request?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use the receivedDateTime filter clause when calling the Graph API, but I'm running into issues when I use the exact datetime. For example, when I try running this API call:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$filter=receivedDateTime ge '2022-05-23T12:29:00'&$orderby=receivedDateTime%20ASC&$top=100&$skip=0`

I get a 400 bad request (the specific error mentions "bad filter clause"). But it works when I run this one:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$filter=receivedDateTime ge 2022-05-23'&$orderby=receivedDateTime%20ASC&$top=100&$skip=0`

What can I do if I want to use the exact datetime in the filter clause, or is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append the `Z` in the ISO 8601 time format, where Z represents the zone designator for the **zero UTC offset**. (e.g. `2022-05-23T11:59:59Z`)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$filter=receivedDateTime ge 2022-05-23T11:59:59Z
```